# Subject in emails not set when using setEmailSubject in docusign api

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using a PHP SDK of docusign. When I set the email subject of the envelop, docusign is using the subject set on the template and not the one set in the api. However, when I look at the sent items in docusign dashboard, the subject is set correctly. Here's a code snippet:

```
                    // instantiate document
                    $docusign_doc = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();
                    $docusign_doc->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode(file_get_contents($document['path'].$document['attachmentsid'].'_'.$document['name'])));
                    $docusign_doc->setName($document['name']);
                    $docusign_doc->setDocumentId("1");

                    // instantiate a new envelope object and configure settings
                    $envelope_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
                    $envelope_definition->setEmailSubject($subject);
                    $envelope_definition->setTemplateId($template_id);
                    $envelope_definition->setTemplateRoles($roles);
                    $envelope_definition->setDocuments(array($docusign_doc));

                    // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
                    $envelope_definition->setStatus("sent");

                    // optional envelope parameters
                    $options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi\CreateEnvelopeOptions();
                    $options->setCdseMode(null);
                    $options->setMergeRolesOnDraft(null);

                    $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelope_definition, $options);
```

Can't find any reference.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? (Specifically the createEnvelope assignment of $envelope_definition)

Comment: There's no official documentation but it seems that this is the normal behavior if you look at the same issue that someone reported [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00084902)

Comment: @Andrew I updated the code. thanks.

Comment: @Frederic will check it out. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Composite Templates to achieve this, the current code that you have will always use the Template emailSubject.

[DocuSign REST API :: Envelopes - Composite Templates](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#composite-templates%20%22DocuSign%20REST%20API%20::%20Envelopes%20-%20Composite%20Templates)